# JQuery, how to access click object after ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this seems like it should be straightforward, but I'm having trouble getting it to work.

I have a .click bind to many buttons of a certain class. When that button is clicked, it passes its id to a $.post call for processing.

When the $.post call returns successfully, I'd like to remove the button and add a message to the container, but I can't seem to even access the button at that point.

Here is the .click bind:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $.post('process.php', {
        action: 'checkit'
    },
    function(result) {
        if (result == 'win') {
            // Access the button that was pressed with jQuery
        }
        else {
            alert("fail");
        }
    });
});
```

I've tried, $(this), this, and also setting a variable like var trigger=this as I enter the initial click function, but none of these are working. I get undefined, or it points to the actual JQuery object, not the button.

Does anyone have any insight into how I can access the button that was clicked at that point, using a jQuery wrapper, essentially something like $( *triggered button* ).html() so that I can manipulate the correct button?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    var $button = $(this);
    $.post('process.php', {
        action: 'checkit'
    },
    function(result) {
        if (result == 'win') {
            $button.doStuff();
        }
        else {
            alert("fail");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow, I swear I tried that. Maybe I screwed up how it was typed, or mistakenly used "this" instead of $(this) somewhere. Thought I had tried all combinations after it failed to work.

Thanks to everyone who commented.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    var clicked = $(this);
    ....
```

Use a local variable for temporary storage.

Comment: +1 - Inside the callback, you would then use `clicked.remove()`.

Comment: +1 - would also reccomend the var name be `$clicked` so that you know it's a jQuery object.

Comment: @johndavidjohn: interesting suggestion, but reminds me too much of PHP :D

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to do:

```
$(this).foo('bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

Is

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $.post('process.php', {
        action: 'checkit'
    },
    function(result) {
        if (result == 'win') {
            $(this).html('something');
        }
        else {
            alert("fail");
        }
    }.bind(this));
});
```

working?

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/FGnvt/2/) of what you are attempting. Click on the text. Just keep a local variable.